# Show that $A(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation $y''-xy=0$ and find the domain of $A(x)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$A(x)=1+\frac{x^3}{2\cdot3}+\frac{x^6}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot6}+\frac{x^9}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot6\cdot8\cdot9}+\cdots$$
Show that $A(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation $y''-xy=0$ and find the domain of $A(x)$.

---

I'm struggling to write a series for the function.  What should I do to prove the first statement and find the answer to the second question?

Comment: To check if $A(x)$ is a solution just plug it in the differential.

Comment: $A(x)$ is a series or  a polynomial?

Comment: $A''(x)=x+\frac{x^4}{2.3}+\frac{x^7}{2.3.5.6}+\dots$, and does domain means radius of convergence here?

Comment: Is there  any initial value ? like $y(0)=1$ ?

Comment: If you want $A(x)$ written in $\sum$ notation (although that doesn't make the task easier), here it is:
$$A(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\prod_{l=0}^{k-1} (3l+1)) x^{3k}}{(3k)!}$$

Comment: You should look up Airy function.